# Installing Canon MG6200 printer on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, printing, canon

Recently upgraded my computer to 18.04 from 16.04 and was excited that my computer seemed to automatically see my Canon MG6200 printer. I could never print from 16.04 and have always has to print from my wife's laptop (windows). Buuuut nothing works and I have never found adequate instructions for installing drivers. Any help would be appreciated, I've spend a lot of time reading about how other users have gotten Canon printers to work, so hoping there is a work around for my printer as well.